# java Gui se bloquea, Comunicacion serial - grafico jfreechart

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un problema con la GUI que se congela, en mi aplicación uso la libreria rxtx 2.1-7 y la libreria jfreechart 1.0.19. Básicamente se establece  la comunicación y se  leen los eventos  de puerto al  recibir  datos. los  datos  se  agregan a una lista y esta  lista se pasa como parámetro a un DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset.  después  de graficar  el GUI se  bloquea  de  manera aleatoria puede  que sea  en dos o tres  segundos o en 10 minutos. siempre despues de graficar. nunca se  bloquea
al establecer comunicacion. modifico  Jpanel para que aparezcan los graficos y Jlabel para poner  el estado del equipo conectado por puerto serial.  no hay ningún reporte  de  error desde el IDE netbeans.
Les  muestro la spartes de o codigo que considero son pertinentes.

```
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {

    while (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) 
    {

        try {
            int data; //Se declaran las variables
            datoa = RecibeDatos(); //Se lee los datos en el puerto serie

            if (data > 0) { 
                Mensaje = Mensaje + (char) data; //acumulamos el  mensaje caracter por caracter
                System.out.println(Mensaje);                    
                if ((Mensaje.charAt(Mensaje.length() - 1) == '&')) 
                { 
                    if(Mensaje.contains("#$%"))
                    {
                        publicador(Mensaje);
                        Mensaje="";
                        break;
                    }
                         Publicadorresultados(Mensaje);
                         Mensaje="";


                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString()+ "      error  mensaje");
        }
    }
}
```

para modificar los  JLabel uso un switch:

```
switch(sel3)   /// evalua el   codigo del  error  para la celda 
                        {
                            case 1: 
                                    Celda1.removeAll();
                                    Celda1.setText("Reset por Panel");
                                    Celda1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                                    Celda1.validate();
                                    Celda1.repaint();  
                            break;        
                            case 2: 
                                    Celda1.removeAll();
                                    Celda1.setText("Error, limpiar celda");
                                    Celda1.setForeground(Color.RED);
                                    Celda1.validate();
                                    Celda1.repaint(); 
                            break;
                            case 3:
                                    Celda1.removeAll();
                                    Celda1.setText("Inicia Test");
                                    Celda1.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
                                    Celda1.validate();
                                    Celda1.repaint(); 
                            break;
```

para graficar :

```
public   void graficador ()
{


    BoxAndWhiskerItem item = BoxAndWhiskerCalculator
    .calculateBoxAndWhiskerStatistics(lista);
    DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset data = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
    data.add(item, "Serie 1", "Test");
    BoxAndWhiskerRenderer renderer = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();
    renderer.setMeanVisible(false);
    renderer.setFillBox(false);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBoxAndWhiskerChart(
    "Diagrama de Cajas","Prueba","Tiempo (s)", data, false);
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
    plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    ChartPanel p1= new ChartPanel(chart);
    p1.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
    CgraficoCaja.removeAll();
    CgraficoCaja.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    CgraficoCaja.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    CgraficoCaja.validate();

    //this.validate();

}
```

pensé  que  era  problema de las librerias y las  he  cambiado, sin embargo se  sigue  congelando la interfaz.  vi en la red  algo acerca  de  no  modificar los elementos SWING desde EDT y en vez  de ello  utilizar  SwingWorker o en otros  casos usar invokelater().  pero no  funciona. el gui se bloquea  y la unica opción es  cerrar  desde  del  ide o el administrador  de  tareas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que correr los procesos en hilos distintos.

> Thread y Runnable

Aqui un ejemplo:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
            //Aqui va el codigo
           //rm.procesar_morosos(IP_Servidor, Procesado, Resumen);
       }
   }).start();
```